# Read values in XML with Jquery : how to do?

Tags: jquery, xml

On a project, I try to change the content of every markup with attribut `data-mlid`. I have the first part of my code but no way to find how to go further. I'm stuck... I hope you'll be able to help me.

1. Loop on every markup with a particular attribut
2. Parse XML to find back the associated language

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var lan = "fr" ;
    var multilan ;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'xml/multilan.xml',
            success: function(xml){
                $("[data-mlid]").each(function(){
                    $(xml).find($(this).data("mlid")).each(function(){
                        //What to do now?? How to find the multilan text back?
                    });
                    $(this).text(multilan);
                })
            }
        }); 
    });
```

HTML

```
<h2 class="stb-text-center" data-mlid="0001"></h2>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translations>
    <multilan id="0001">
        <en>Welcome!</en>
        <fr>Bienvenue !</fr>
    </multilan>
</translations>
```

Thank you!

Comment: How exactly do you want to improve it?

Comment: @Adeneo gave a right answer. But I would like to know how to insert html and interpret html in my XML. Indeed, some of my texts contains links such as `Forgot password? <a href="abc.html">Reset</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an ID, and in jQuery those are prefixed with `#`, so it's

```
$(xml).find('#' + $(this).data("mlid")).each(function() {
    var en = $(this).find('em').text();
    var fr = $(this).find('fr').text();
});
```

Also, you should add the right dataType to the ajax call to make sure it's properly parsed with $.parseXML

```
$.ajax({
     dataType: 'xml',
     url:  ...
```

Comment: I don't call food parseXml. Is it automatic when we make a find on a xml document? However, thank you for the answer. It works as expected.

Comment: @DescampsAu - You should set the dataType to XML when getting XML, and if the answer works, adding the `#` etc, feel free to accept it.